# Separating then Joining Text and Data

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    WebBrowser2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    WebBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/")
    WaitForPageLoad2()
    Dim usernme As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim first As String
    Dim last As String
    Dim addrs As String
    Dim city As String
    Dim postal As String
    Dim state As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim full As String
    Dim fullstat As String
    Dim docum As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In docum
        If CurElement.GetAttribute("classname") = "address" Then
            full = CurElement.InnerText
            MsgBox(full)
        End If
    Next
    ListBox1.Items.Add(full)
End Sub
```

im trying to get first last / first and last /address /state/zipcode i can not wrap my head around it tho btw the full var is the one im splting up because when i grab the info from fake name generator it comes all bunched up like Steven N. Henry 1203 Benson Park Drive Oklahoma City, OK 73109
please help :) thank you

Comment: you should show the return data you are trying to parse.  it may well be in am easy to parse format if we could see it.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/6fae5df1366c9174930fa55e1605353d

^ that is all in one string var

Comment: guys ?? i need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to:

```
    Dim splitArray = full.Split(" ")
    For each str in splitArray
            listbox1.Items.Add(str)
    Next
```